# A nonnegative function times an increasing sequence of pairwise disjoint sets

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(S,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space. Suppose $f$ is a nonnegative and measurable function.
If $\{A_{i}\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ are disjoint and measurable, let $A = \bigcup_{i} A_{i}$, and define
$$
E_{n} = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}
$$
Then $E_{n} \uparrow A$. Show tha $f 1_{E_{n}} \uparrow f1_{A}$.

**My try**

To show that $f 1_{E_n} \uparrow f1_{A}$, we need to show that:

$f 1_{E_n} \leq f$ for all $n$, and
$f 1_{E_n} \uparrow f$ pointwise, i.e., for every $x\in S$, we have $f 1_{E_n}(x) \uparrow f(x)$ as $n\to \infty$.
For 1, note that $1_{E_n} \leq 1_{E_{n+1}}$ for all $n$, since $E_n\subseteq E_{n+1}$ for all $n$. Therefore, $f 1_{E_n} \leq f 1_{E_{n+1}}$ for all $n$, since $f$ is non-negative. Moreover, $f 1_{E_n} \leq f$ for all $n$, since $1_{E_n} \leq 1_A$ and $f$ is non-negative.

For 2, fix $x\in S$. We have two cases to consider: either $x\in A$, or $x\not\in A$.

If $x\in A$, then there exists $i$ such that $x\in A_i$, and so $1_{E_n}(x) = 1$ for all $n\geq i$. Therefore, we have $f 1_{E_n}(x) = f(x)$ for all $n\geq i$, and so $f 1_{E_n}(x) \uparrow f(x)$ as $n\to \infty$.

If $x\not\in A$, then $x\not\in A_i$ for all $i$. Therefore, $1_{E_n}(x) = 0$ for all $n$ and $f 1_{E_n}(x) = 0$ for all $n$. Therefore, $f 1_{E_n}(x) \uparrow 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Putting 1 and 2 together, we have shown that $f 1_{E_n} \uparrow f1_{A}$.

**Question**

My proof is tedious, is there any theorem or trick that can simplify my proof?

Comment: @Anne Bauval: Then, how can I fix my proof as well as simplifying it?

Comment: @Anne Bauval: I fixed it. You can edit my question is you see I have missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f≥0,$
in order to prove $f1_{En}↑f1_A,$
you just have to show that
[$$1_{E_n}↑1_A.$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432012)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why nonnegativeness implies that. Why when $f\geq0$ you can multiply? Also, how to show $1_{E_n} \uparrow 1_A$.

Comment: About "how to show....": just like you did, or follow the link I included. About "why nonnegativeness implies that": because multiplying by $f\ge0$ preserves monotonicity of the sequence (and preserves pointwise convergence, even when $f$ not $\ge0$).